# using find with mmin & cmin

Tags: find

I have a file in a directory that was created on "12/9/2022 12:34" and Modified on "01/21/2023 18:27" however when I perform a `find` (on the same date as the modified date at "18:42") using `-cmin +120` the file is retuning in my search.

Here is my command line:

```
find /media/folder1/backup1/machine1/backup/ -cmin +120 -type f
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using `rsync` to move files to a different directory when deleted. When it moves the file it updates the name of the file. Once the file has been moved if I perform a `ls -l` I can see the original date the file was created, if I do a `ls -lc` I can see the date that the file name was changed. I want to perform a `find` on the second date so I can purge the files after 90 days. (I was am using `cmin` for testing)

I figured out the issue, essentially I have an SMB mount from Server A to Desktop B, when I perform a `ls -lc` or a `ls -l` on Desktop A it shows the same date for both values on the document. Now if I go to Server A (which is where the file actually lives) and perform the same commands, I get DIFFERENT dates for the values. I have tried googling why it does this, but I am not having any luck

Comment: +120 would mean older than 120 minutes. Try with -120 instead.

Comment: Most linux filesystems don't support creation time, and "ctime" is actually change time.  ctime is updated on chmod, utimes, or any other file metadata or data modification, where mtime is only updated if the file is written to.  Likely your source fs is NTFS or something that does support creation time.

Comment: If you don't see the ctime on the mount, look at the samba-options used for exporting and for mounting. Unix extensions should be enabled there, also (depending ob your kernel) CIFS should be used instead of smbfs.